# Freeze certain layers of an existing model in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using the mobileNetV2  and I only want to freeze part of the model. I know I can use the following code to freeze the entire model

```
MobileNet = models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained = True)

for param in MobileNet.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

but I want everything from (15) onward to remain unfrozen. How can I selectively freeze everything before the desired layer is frozen?

```
    (15): InvertedResidual(
      (conv): Sequential(
        (0): ConvBNReLU(
          (0): Conv2d(160, 960, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(960, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
        )
        (1): ConvBNReLU(
          (0): Conv2d(960, 960, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=960, bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(960, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Conv2d(960, 160, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (3): BatchNorm2d(160, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (16): InvertedResidual(
      (conv): Sequential(
        (0): ConvBNReLU(
          (0): Conv2d(160, 960, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(960, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
        )
        (1): ConvBNReLU(
          (0): Conv2d(960, 960, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=960, bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(960, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Conv2d(960, 160, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (3): BatchNorm2d(160, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (17): InvertedResidual(
      (conv): Sequential(
        (0): ConvBNReLU(
          (0): Conv2d(160, 960, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(960, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
        )
        (1): ConvBNReLU(
          (0): Conv2d(960, 960, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=960, bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(960, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Conv2d(960, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (3): BatchNorm2d(320, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (18): ConvBNReLU(
      (0): Conv2d(320, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(1280, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): ReLU6(inplace=True)
    )   )   (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
    (1): Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=1000, bias=True)   ) )
```

Answer (score 37):

Start by freezing everything:

```
for param in MobileNet.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Then, unfreeze parameters in (15):

```
for param in MobileNet.features[15].parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
```

Or, unfreeze parameters in (15)-(18):

```
for i in range(15, 19):
    for param in MobileNet.features[i].parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True
```

Answer (score 24):

Just adding this here for completeness. You can also freeze parameters in place without iterating over them with `requires_grad_` ([API](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad_.html)).

For example say you have a RetinaNet and want to just fine-tune on the heads

```py
class RetinaNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.backbone = ResNet(...)
        self.fpn = FPN(...)
        self.box_head = torch.nn.Sequential(...)
        self.cls_head = torch.nn.Sequential(...)
```

Then you could freeze the backbone and FPN like this:

```py
# Getting the model
retinanet = RetinaNet(...)

# Freezing backbone and FPN
retinanet.backbone.requires_grad_(False)
retinanet.fpn.requires_grad_(False)
```

Comment: Good solution if you don't have  much blocks.  However, if you have a lot than it's easier to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define some layers by name and then unfreeze them, I propose a  variant of @JVGD's answer:

```py
class RetinaNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.backbone = ResNet(...)
        self.fpn = FPN(...)
        self.box_head = torch.nn.Sequential(...)
        self.cls_head = torch.nn.Sequential(...)

# Getting the model
retinanet = RetinaNet(...)

# The param name is f'{module_name}.weight' or f'{module_name}.bias'.
# Some layers, e.g., batch norm, have additional params.
# In some circumstances, e.g., when using DataParallel(), 
# the param name is prefixed by 'module.'.
params_to_train = ['cls_head.weight', 'cls_head.bias']
for name, param in retinanet.named_parameters():
    # Set True only for params in the list 'params_to_train'
    param.requires_grad = True if name in params_to_train else False
...
```

The advantage is that you can **define all layers to unfreeze in one `Iterable`**.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are different types of models sometimes setting `required_grad=True` on the blocks alone does not work*.

Option 1

```
# freeze everything
for param in model.parameters():
     param.requires_grad = False

# and Un-Freeze lower 4 layers of encoder 
for i in range(0,num_encoder_layers-8,1):
    for param in model.encoder.block[i].parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True
#verify
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name,param.requires_grad)
```

Option 2

```
# Freeze upper 3 layers of encoder (lower is unfreezed)
 for i in range(num_encoder_layers-1,num_encoder_layers-4,-1):
     for param in model.encoder.block[i].parameters():
         param.requires_grad = False

# Freeze all layers of decoder
for i in range(num_decoder_layers):
    for param in model.decoder.block[i].parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name,param.requires_grad)
```

Depending on what you have frozen you get something like this

Ouput

```
shared.weight False
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.relative_attention_bias.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.0.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight True
encoder.block.0.layer.1.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.0.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight True
encoder.block.1.layer.1.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.0.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight True
encoder.block.2.layer.1.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.0.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight True
encoder.block.3.layer.1.layer_norm.weight True
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.4.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.5.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.6.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.7.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.8.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.9.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.10.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.1.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
encoder.block.11.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
encoder.final_layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.0.SelfAttention.relative_attention_bias.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.0.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.1.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.2.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.3.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.4.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.5.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.6.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.7.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.8.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.9.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.10.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.0.SelfAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.0.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.1.EncDecAttention.q.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.1.EncDecAttention.k.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.1.EncDecAttention.v.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.1.EncDecAttention.o.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.1.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_0.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wi_1.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.2.DenseReluDense.wo.weight False
decoder.block.11.layer.2.layer_norm.weight False
decoder.final_layer_norm.weight False
lm_head.weight False
```

- Example this DO NOT WORK

```
for i in range(-num_encoder_layers//2, 0):  
    model.encoder.block[i].requires_grad = True
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized answer to the first answer above is to freeze only the first 15 layers  [0-14] because the last layers [15-18] are **by default** unfrozen (`param.requires_grad = True`).

Therefore, we only need to code this way:

```
MobileNet = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained = True)

for param in MobileNet.features[0:14].parameters():
      param.requires_grad = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the required layers using this snippet :

```
for name, child in MobileNet.named_children:
    if name < 15 :
        for param in child.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
```